# seambay webservice example unable to deploy on weblogic10.0MP1

Tags: web-services, seam

I need to develop jax ws webservice using seam and deploy the same on weblogic.Tried few things but nothing worked.
So was trying seambay example, while deploying the ear on weblogic I am getting following error.

Unable to deploy EJB: AuctionService from ../jboss-seam-bay.jar:

Unable to deploy EJB: ../jboss-seam-bay.jar from ../jboss-seam-bay.jar:

[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "WSEE_SERVLET" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/Auctio
nService".
class: org.jboss.seam.example.seambay.jaxws.Login could not be found
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:272)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:566
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:513)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:358)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:245)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:229)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:161)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:291)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:315)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:125)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:64)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelp
er.java:282)
But the same ear works fine on JBOSS and was able to get the wsdl.
What changes do I need to get it worked on weblogic.I did all the basic changes which I need to do to deploy a seam ear on weblogic.

In the build file i was not able to see any ant task like wsgen etc to create the jax ws artifacts.Only change what I have seen is adding the
/META-INF/standard-jaxws-endpoint-config.xml file which is JBOSS specific.

Im totally clueless as how should I procced now.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

watch here:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=756111&tstart=0